# How to foreach with && sign in condition php

Tags: php

Good day Sir / Ma'am! I am newbie programmer. I would like to ask how I can use the `&&` sign as a condition in the `foreach` statement? I searched for the solution but could only find results for C#. I'm sorry if my English grammar is poor. Also please excuse me if you find the question too easy as I am a newbie.

My sample code is:

```
$accountval = array();
$accountidval = array();

$account = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM account where region = '$regionval' ");

while($rowaccount = mysql_fetch_array($account))
{
$accountval[] = $rowaccount['accountname'];
$accountidval[] = $rowaccount['id'];
}

foreach($accountval as $key => $accountname && $accountidval as $key1 =>$accountid)
            {
            echo "<option value='{$accountid}'>".$accountname."</option>";
            }
```

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `array_combine()`

```
foreach (array_combine($accountval, $accountidval) as $accountname => $accountid) {
    echo '<option value="' . $accountid . '">' . $accountname . '</option>';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach(array_merge($accountval=>$accountname,$accountidval=>$accountid)) as $key {echo "";}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have a condition inside the `foreach` statement. [See the official documentation of here](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php). You will need utilize the `for` loop, and maybe the `if` statement depending upon your exact need.